# Make Scale / Window Picker preserve relative window positions?

Tags: unity, compiz, window-management

When I use the Scale feature in Ubuntu 14.04, the miniature versions of the windows are not in the same relative positions on the screen as the actual windows.

Suppose, for example, that I have 2 terminal windows open, one on the left and one on the right.  They look essentially identical in miniature, but must be distinguished from each other, e.g., because they have different environment variables and pwds.  Hence, I keep them separate on the screen, one on the left and one on the right.

When I use Scale to navigate to one of these windows (among several other non-terminal windows), it sometimes (though not always) shows the the left window on the right and the right window on the left.  So, I click on the wrong one and I essentially can't use Scale to navigate identical looking windows based on geometry.

Is there a way to make Scale preserve relative positions as much as possible, esp. for windows that are running the same application and thus look identical in miniature?